# Beacon detection stops when giving ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, altbeacon, beacon

I have set beacon background scan [using this tutorial](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) in `BaseApplication` class but in **Marshmallow** running device it shows this log:

```
Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
java.lang.SecurityException: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results
```

And finally with [this](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/09/29/is-your-beacon-app-ready-for-android-6.html) and [this](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/requesting_permission.html) reference i was able to give location access for Marshmallow running device to detect beacons.

**My Problem:**

Even when i give Location access it doesn't detect beacons and also stops to show **above Log**. Is it the problem as in this [ISSUE](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/301). My Nexus 5 Build number is **MRA58N**

**UPDATE:** When i turn on Location manually now it works. But it's strange. Is it right way to detect beacon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Marshmallow introduces an entirely new spin on application permissions,Users now have the ability to revoke runtime permissions whenever they desire. This means that you can’t assume the app has access to the permission, even if it had been granted previously. You can refer [this lib](http://hotchemi.github.io/PermissionsDispatcher/) or [this guide](https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-the-new-android-permissions-model-ba1d5d6c0610#.1jpsx34a6). And you can create a interface listener location changed after enable GPS, when location != 0. After enable GPS you must resume. I Hope this will help you out.